# Are there $0$-$1$-matrices that are not unimodular?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am just wondering if there are matrices that only consists of $0$s and a few $1$s that are not [totally unimodular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity) (TU)? I cannot come up with an example but I am not very experienced with this stuff.

In a specific case, if I have a very sparse $0$-$1$ matrix where every row consist of at most two $1$s and every column consists of at most three $1$s, how can I find out whether this matrix is TU?

I cannot use [the four sufficient conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Common_totally_unimodular_matrices) for $A$ to be totally unimodular (where $B$, $C$ is a disjoint partition of the rows of $A$), because condition $3$ might be violated:

1. Every column of contains at most two non-zero entries;
2. Every entry in is $0, +1$, or $−1$;
3. If two non-zero entries in a column of have the same sign, then the row of one is in $B$, and the other in $C$;
4. If two non-zero entries in a column of have opposite signs, then the rows of both are in $B$, or both in $C$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is a (very simple) $2 \times 2$ example where the determinant is $0$.
Any $3 \times 3$ example with all rows having two $1$'s that does not have determinant $0$ has determinant $\pm 2$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Than seems to be rather easy. However, the 2-2 matrix with determinant 0 would still be TU. And the matrices I have are very large and usually don't contain columns with two consecutuve 1s.

Comment: Any square submatrix that has a row or column containing only one $1$ is unimodular iff the sub-submatrix obtained by deleting the row and column with that $1$ is unimodular.  So you want to look at 
square submatrices where all rows and columns have two $1$'s.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Observe that the [determinant of this matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant%20of%20%7B%7B1,1,1,1%7D,%7B1,0,0,1%7D,%7B0,1,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,1,1%7D%7D) is two so the matrix is not totally unimodular as required.

Note: credit for this example goes to Camion for his nice characterization of TU matrices in his 1965 paper (see citation below).

*Camion, P.*, [**Characterization of totally unimodular matrices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2035618), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 16, 1068-1073 (1965). [ZBL0134.25201](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0134.25201).

Comment: Israel's $3\times3$ example is correct and your comment about it is wrong. E.g. $\det\pmatrix{0&1&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 1&1&0}=2$. Note that every matrix is a submatrix of itself. We are not only talk about proper submatrices in the definition of TU.

Comment: Yep, you are right! My mistake. The answer has been updated.